# Mapping through elements in array and displaying them in a paragraph

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have an array containing 3 elements and I want to map through them (create a `<a>` tag for each of them), and join them by a `,`. When I use .join to join the elements in the array, this is being displayed: [with .join(', ')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg3Oc.png). Is there any reason why this is happening?
This is my code (using react with jsx):

```js
const items = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3'];

return <p> {items.map((m) => {
return <a href={`#${m}`}>{m}</a>;
}).join(', ')}
</p>
```

The code does work if I don't join the array, but then the text looks ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.join()` will force your JSX to string and you will get `[Object object]`. You can add `,` based on the index of `item` like `(i ? ', ' : '')` to make your item comma separated.

```js
const App = () => {
const items = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3'];

return (
  <p> 
    {
     items.map((m, i) => {
      return <a href={`#${m}`}>{(i ? ', ' : '') + m}</a>;
     })
    }
  </p>)
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```